# Casting generic delegate Action<T> to Action<string>

Tags: c#, .net-core, publish-subscribe

I am working on implementing pub/sub pattern for cache use. The following class is suppose to be used to publish any type of data. And subscribers can attach a callback of `Action` `T` on the event. But I couldn't create a generic event at the class level without making the class generic and I don't want to do that. So I have tried to cast the values back and forth to string using `JsonSerializer` as follows.

```
public class CacheNotification
{
    public Action<string> CachePublished;

    public Task Publish<T>(T value)
    {
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(value);
        OnCachePublished(json);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback)
    {
        Action<string> newCallback = (string json) => 
                             callback(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json));
        CachePublished += newCallback;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    
    protected virtual void OnCachePublished(string value)
    {
        if(CachePublished != null){
              CachePublished.Invoke(value);
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is on the subscribe method, the casting I attempted only works for `Action` string. It fails on `Action` `int` or `Action` `object`

```
public Task Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback)
{
   Action<string> newCallback = (string json) => 
                     callback(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json));
   CachePublished += newCallback;
   return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Here is a test I used. This fails for second subscriber

```
Action<string> sub1Callback = msg =>
{
    sub1Counter++;
};

Action<int> sub2Callback = num =>
{
    sub2Counter++;
};

var sub1 = await cache.Subscribe(sub1Callback);
var sub2 = await cache.Subscribe(sub2Callback);

await cache.Publish("Value1");
Assert.Equal(1, sub1Counter);
Assert.Equal(1, sub2Counter);
```

Comment: Hi, what exception do you will get when your code fails?

Comment: Based on your last snippet alone, what are you expecting to happen when publishing only a string? Your explanation is very confusing on what precisely you expect to have happen. Should only the action of the same type of the passed value be triggered? What is the purpose of merging these two totally different subscriptions then? You also didn't post the initial value of `sub1Counter` and `sub2Counter` so the assert statement convey no information to the reader.

Comment: _"But I couldn't create a generic event at the class level without making the class generic and I don't want to do that."_ Why not do you not want to do the thing that solves the problem at hand?

Comment: Also, while there are conversions possible between ints and (some!) strings, what do you expect to happen when dealing with a type that has no possible conversion to another type?

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I see the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is here:

> Action sub2Callback = num =>

after

> await cache.Publish("Value1");

Your:

```
public Task Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback)
{
    Action<string> newCallback = (string json) => callback(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json));

    CachePublished += newCallback;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

tries to deserialize "Value1" to integer and it correctly fails. It cannot be done.

Try to send integer value instead of "Value1" and it should work.

Another way is to refactor your Subscribe method to be independent of given type, but this cannot be done according to your intentions I guess.